# Twitter4J Creating Callback URL That Goes Back To My App

Tags: java, android, twitter, callback, twitter4j

I've read through this: [Android: Login with Twitter using Twitter4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306237/android-login-with-twitter-using-twitter4j)

And the selected answer doesn't make sense in the context that I need it.

I want the user to be able to login to their Twitter account from our app, and then, once they've logged in, I want our app to reload.

It loads the twitter webpage (although I wish they could just login within my app instead of needing the browser) but then I'm not sure how to set 'my application' as the callback.

Can you advise where I can find (or set if it doesnt exist) the callback URL so when the user logs into Twitter it our app re-opens?

This is my login code:

```
    public void loginUser()
    {
        //Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
//What do I set my TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL as?
                requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       } else {            
       // user already logged into twitter
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt quite figure out how the intents-in-manifest business worked.

Instead I did the following (and it works)

1. Created a WebViewClient and overrided its shouldOverrideUrlLoading
2. Set this WebViewClient to the webview and load the twitter login from there.
3. In my WebView client I am parsing the twitter response looking for my string (which can be anything). If its there, I hide the webview.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
       Log.d("Loading webview", url);
       if (url.contains(TwitterActivity.CALLBACK_URL)) {
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
           String oauthVerifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
           _twitterActivty.closeTwitterBrowser(oauthVerifier);
           return false;
       }
       view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry for code formatting, but the code brackets are bugging out (i.e. its not working). By forcing it into quotes I got it to display easier to read